# How to update a item value of a list?

Tags: c#, list

i have a list. Where i put all my query output. Now do some processing using 
thread. so when work is completed then need to update the list item value.
please see my code below:

publicly declared list:

```
public static List<string[]> OutboxList = new List<string[]>();
```

fetch the data from database and manipulate the list:

```
OutboxQueryCommand.CommandText = "SELECT top 5 id, status from TableA";      
SqlDataReader OutboxQueryReader = OutboxQueryCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (OutboxQueryReader.Read())
{
    string[] OutBoxFields = new string[7];
    OutBoxFields[0] = OutboxQueryReader["id"].ToString();
    OutBoxFields[1] = OutboxQueryReader["status"].ToString();
    OutboxList.Add(OutBoxFields);
}

foreach (string[] OutBoxFields in OutboxList)
{
    id = OutBoxFields[0];
    status = OutBoxFields[1];

    Thread OutboxThread = new Thread(() => OutboxThreadProcessor(id,status));
    OutboxThread.Start();
}
```

Call the method by thread:

```
 static void OutboxThreadProcessor(string id,string status)
   {
//predefine value of status is "QUE". Process some work here for that perticular item list.if data process success full then need to update 
// the status of the list item 

// need to update the perticular value of that list item here.
How i do it???????
//Say for Example 1-> Success
//            2-> Failed
//            3-> Success            
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the array directly to `Thread` so that you can update the array once you're done.

```
static void OutboxThreadProcessor(string[] OutBoxFields)
{
    string id = OutBoxFields[0];
    string status = OutBoxFields[1];

    //Do work

    OutBoxFields[0] = "2";//update the array
    OutBoxFields[1] = "something";
}
```

Call it like this

```
Thread OutboxThread = new Thread(() => OutboxThreadProcessor(OutBoxFields));
OutboxThread.Start();
```

Also note that you're closing over the loop in this scenario, this is fine if you're building in c#5.0 compiler this is fine, else you need to use a local variable inside the loop.

Comment: static list passing through the thread showing error..can you please help?  Thread OutboxThread = new Thread(() => OutboxThreadProcessor(OutboxList));

Comment: You're passing list variable `OutboxList`. Look at my answer you should pass `OutBoxFields`

Comment: i have try the OutboxFileds Also. but both showing error..Thread OutboxThread = new Thread(() => OutboxThreadProcessor(OutBoxFields)); is there any restriction for list ..??

Comment: Error 1 No overload for method 'OutboxThreadProcessor' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Did you look at my answer? `static void OutboxThreadProcessor(string[] OutBoxFields)` modify your method signature like this

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer if it helped. and consider user dasblinkenlight's solution converting your code to Object oriented

Answer (score 1):

You need to find an item in your list of arrays where `item[0]` is equal to `id`, and set the `status` into `item[1]`. You can do it with a loop, like this

```
foreach (string[] item in OutboxList) {
    if (item[0] == id) {
        item[1] = status;
        break;
    }
}
```

or with LINQ, like this:

```
var item = OutboxList.FirstOrDefault(a => a[0] == id);
if (item != null) {
    item[1] = status;
}
```

Note that your data structures are not particularly object-oriented. Your program would be more readable if you replaced an array of seven `string` items with a `class` that has seven string fields, like this:

```
class OutBoxFields {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Status {get;set;}
    ... // and so on
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But non of this code block is work into the OutboxThreadProcessor method.. is there any update needed???

Comment: Is `OutboxThreadProcessor` a static method in the same class where your static `OutboxList` field is defined?