# Update items in List<T> c#

Tags: c#, list

I have a class to handle some data :

```
public class User
{
  public string Name;
  public string Date;
}
```

In another class,i create a `List` of `User` class and add data as follows :

```
public class Display
{
  List<User> userData = new List<User>;

  private void add()
  {
    User udata = new User;
    udate.Name = "Abc";
    udata.Date = "1/1/18";
    userData.Add(udata);
  }
}
```

My question is, after adding some data,how do i update it ? Say i have added a data(`udata` is what i mean) with a `Name` of `ABC`,how do i update it?

Comment: Do you mean change the `User` that you entered?

Comment: @Tim,yes...That's what i mean

Comment: You access the object from your list and change the value

Comment: @PraveenPaulose,can u show me a sample code please

Comment: this feels like you haven't really learnt C# yet.  But all your objects are in userData..... you can access the userData list...... ```userData[0].Name = "xyz"```

Comment: userData[0].Name ="ABC"

Comment: You're trying to complicate something that is very simple.  You can basically treat each item in the `List` like a variable.  How would you modify a `User` object assigned to a variable?  This is no different.

Comment: What should i replace [0] with ? or should i keep it as it is ?

Comment: 0 is the index of the item in the list. You can read accessing items in a List

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a item value of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065774/how-to-update-a-item-value-of-a-list)

Comment: there are actually many duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your list contains a mutable type, all you need to do is get a reference to the specific item you want to update.
That can be done in a number of ways - using it's index, using the `Find` method, or using linq are the first three that comes to mind.

Using [index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
userData[0]?.Name = "CBA";
```

Using [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
userData.Find(u => u.Name = "Abc")?.Name = "CBA";
```

Using linq ([FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039(v=vs.110).aspx) is not the only option):

```
userData.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name = "Abc")?.Name = "CBA";
```

Note the use of [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (`]?` and `.?`) it prevents a null reference exception in case the item is not found.

### Update

As Ak77th7 commented (thanks for that!), the code in this answer wasn't tested and will cause a compilation error -

> error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable,
> property or indexer

The reason for this is the null-conditional operator (`?.`).
You can use it to get values from properties, but not for setting them.

The fix is either to accept the fact that your code might throw a `NullReferenceException` (which I personally believe has no room in production-grade code) or to make your code a bit more cumbersome:

```cs
// Note: Possible null here!
userData.Find(u => u.Name.EndsWith("1")).Name = "Updated by Find";

// Safe, but cumbersome
var x = userData.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name.EndsWith("2"));
if(x is not null)
{
    x.Name = "Updated by FirstOrDefault";
}
```

See a live demo on [SharpLab.IO](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: so, [o] is the index right ? I need to first find out the index and then update it ?

Comment: Dear downvoter: How could you possibly read the answer if you downvoted it 100 ms I've posted it?

Comment: @ZoharPeled someone did the same to my answer. Seems to be happening a lot tonight.

Comment: @Dr.Blake If you don't know the index in advance, then I suggest using another method to retrieve the item

Comment: @Tim thanks! I don't really mind the downvote, it was just surprising it was so fast. I've seen perfectly good answers getting downvoted just because they answer beginners questions, perhaps that's the same case here.

Comment: @ZoharPeled well I liked the answer too, so it was an honest upvote. I think you're correct about the cause.

Comment: A downvote is often a pathway to get a free upvote as people try and correct the situation when they wouldn't of given you an upvote in the first place :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas As I wrote, I don't really mind the downvote, I was just surprised it happend so fast.... but yeah, I agree.

Comment: Ur 1st solution worked....anyway , is there a bug in SO ?? My qs is getting upvoted and downvoted every second ...y ???

Comment: Not a bug, there are a lop of users in the community, some don't like "easy" questions, and as Keith wrote, downvotes will often cause someone else to upvote just to even the score...

Comment: Although this is old, I doubt if the FirstOrDefault() is a working version or being tested. 
`Error CS0131 The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`. So goes for the Find() too, unless we assign to a variable and then set the value.

Comment: @Ak777 You are correct. I've updated my answer, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing tricky, really (but does use `System.Linq`)
**EDIT: Changed Single to First to avoid error if there are two users with the same name. **

```
void Update(string name, string newName)
{
    var user = userData.First(u => u.Name == name);
    user.Name = newName;
}
```

Notice this changes the object, and the List maintains reference to the changed object.

Comment: and where does it update ? I don't see such code :( ?

Comment: @Dr.Blake, anyone can vote. You can ignore it as far as your solution goes. If it helps, use it.

Comment: what if there a re multiple data with the same `Name`,but what makes them unique is their `Date` , will this still work ?

Comment: @Dr.Blake, no, you should give each `User` a unique key, such as an `Id` `int`.

Comment: as long as you keep a reference to the user you can update it.   With the code shown, you put it in the list, so the list is the only thing that has a reference to the user, so you have to find it in the list, but depending what you are trying to do, you can put it anywhere you want

Comment: Not sure I would go with `Single` here - since it will throw an exception if you have two elements with the same name.

Comment: It asserts that only one entry is updated (which can be desirable) but comes at a performance penalty. If you know the entry is unique then I'd definitely use First instead.